# Getting data from cache while cache is false

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following code to automatically login to my email account:

```
$.ajax({
   async: false,
   cache: false,
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'html',
   data: ({
       '_token': token_value,
       '_task': 'login',
       '_action': 'login',
       '_timezone': '2',
       '_dstactive': '0',
       '_url': '',
       '_user': _username,
       '_pass': _password
   }),
   url: 'https://mail.somesite.com/index.php',
   success: function (data) {
       //after login get the central email page where the email count is displayed
       $.ajax({
           async: false,
           cache: false,
           type: 'GET',
           dataType: 'html',
           url: 'https://mail.somesite.com/index.php?_task=mail',
           success: function(data1) {
               var descNode = document.createElement("div");
               descNode.innerHTML = data1;
               var unreadcount = descNode.getElementsByClassName("unreadcount");
            /*process unreadcount etc*/
         },
         error: function () {
            // something went wrong with the request
            error_occurred();
            return;
         }
      });
   },
   error: function () {
      // something went wrong with the request
      error_occurred();
      return;
   }
})
```

The problem is that, after getting an object with class "unreadcount" so as to get the unread email count of the user, I get an old page.

For example, if I login to my email account, see that I have 2 emails and I run this function, I will be informed that I have 2 emails. If I log out from my account, send an email from another account to my account and re-run this function, it will not find the new email (it will still show only 2 emails). I've tried seeing the contents of data1 with `console.log()` and I am pretty sure that the function does nothing wrong (because the value of 'unreadcount' is indeed still 2).

Of course, when I normally login, I can see that I have 3 emails into my account. The strange (?) thing is that after loggin in (even if I log out, after this) and run the above function, it will find the third email.

All these led me to the conclusion that I am led to a cache page, but I've set cache to false in any occassion. How can I avoid this from happening?

Comment: Or it is not cache, but the server/your email client 'knows' somehow that your not viewing your email trough your browser ('cause you're using an ajax call) and doesn't fetch the new e-mails from the server. Don't know if that's possible but I can imagine that the server sees these things differently. Don't think it's cache, but to be sure you could add an unique parameter to your url (eg. https://mail.somesite.com/index.php?_task=mail&9102831).

Comment: What should I expect from the unique parameter @SanderBruggeman ?

Comment: I don't think it will make any difference, mainly because I think it's my first suggestion: your mail client doesn't fetch new e-mails if you try to reach/get the page trough an Ajax call.. The unique parameter is just to make sure it's always a different url, so it doesn't fetch it from cache (which I'm pretty sure it doesn't anyway, but still).

Comment: I just thought of a reason why this occurs: your email client also uses an ajax call (or something similar) to fetch your new email AFTER the page is loaded. Maybe it's too fast too see, but when you visit your email client trough your browser, does it sometimes take a minute to load new e-mails? Or does your client have a custom pre-loader? (I know Gmail does, that would probably also not work..)

Comment: @SanderBruggeman yes, you are 100% correct! Once the page is loaded there is no email counter there. But after ~100ms the counter takes its place! So, your theory that the new emails are added after some call and not immediately is correct. Any possible solution to this? After fetching the page can I "wait" for this counter to take its place and then take its value or something like this is not possible? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No, you can't, unfortunately. Or there must be some way I don't know. I'm afraid you will have to do a completely different approach. Does your email client have pop3 o.i.d? php can work with that (you could then do an ajax request to your own php file which uses pop3/imap to fetch new e-mails). Google your email client + pop3 if you're not sure. There are also a lot of php examples on how to use pop3/imap with php + an email client.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not only wait for page to load but for a content of it to be updated via an ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922970/not-only-wait-for-page-to-load-but-for-a-content-of-it-to-be-updated-via-an-ajax)